# In Visual Studio 2017, is there a fast way to add "std::" to names that lack it?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I have a project which was originally designed with `using namespace std;`.  Due to that, names in `std` could be accessed without appending `std::` in front of the name.

However, some of the names already have `std::` tacked in front due to needing to disambiguate argument dependent lookup and name collisions in the code.

For example:

```
unique_ptr<uint8_t[]> token = make_unique<uint8_t[]>(count);
/* some other code */
process(std::forward<T>(tmp_map));
```

Assuming my code is currently in a working state (i.e. current code that does not use `std::` refer to the intended objects, whether in `std` or not), would there be a way to add `std::` to all the names that are lacking it, that is faster than manually inspecting each name in the code?

The IDE probably needs to be able to understand the code to some extent (instead of just doing a textual find/replace), but Visual Studio has Intellisense - can I exploit that or something else to accomplish my task?

I would be happy even if it fixes most (but not all) occurences, but anyone knows of a way to do so?

Comment: That's the type of thing that can be done by writing code for clang, but it's not trivial and I don't know any way to do it in VS

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

First replace all `using namespace std;` with . Then do the following for every `_type_` in the STL that your project utilizes:

- replace all `_type_` with `std::_type_`
- replace all `std::std::` with `std::`

Comment: Hmm, this should work for all `_type_`s that aren't also defined in any other namespace and also for functions such as `make_unique`.

Comment: In case that a `_type_` is also defined in another namespace `_foo_` you need to replace all `_foo_::std::_type_` with `_foo_::_type_`.